# Is there any benefit to transform strings into integers before compare two strings(which are integer)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Recently I've written a update program which reads .ini info from remote.
It obtain the version value from the .ini file, example : version=4

My program grabs the string after "version=", which is a string "4"，
I tried to compare it with another string, which is "5"

example code:

```
string first_value = "4";
string second_value = "5";

//compare two values
if ( first_value < second_value){
    cout << "4 is smaller than 5" <<endl;
}else{
    cout << "5 is smaller than 4" <<endl;
}
```

the above code works, c++ must has transformed them into integer for me, so it works.

However I wonder if it is better to transform "first_value" and "second_value" into integer first then compare both integer?
Is there any benefit to do this? Any better way to write my comparing code?

Comment: Try with other numbers than 4 and 5, maybe 4 and 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. The operator< for String is just comparing the alphabet order of the two parameters. That means,"099" is not equal to "99"(the **first** **character** of "*099*" is "0", the **first** **character** of "*99*" is "9", when you compare their alphabet order, "0"<"9", so "*099*"<"*99*"), for another example, `"19" < "9"`.
You can see that is certainly not true.

Comment: Nice explanation, the above comment completely solved my blind spot. Thank you :)